# Trying to add TheAmazingAudioEngine via cocoapods and failing miserably

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I created a podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target :MyApp do
  pod 'TheAmazingAudioEngine'
end
```

ran pod setup, pod install, and pod update...  Got:

> Update all pods
>
> Updating local specs repositories
>
> Analyzing dependencies
>
> Downloading dependencies
>
> Using TheAmazingAudioEngine (1.5.1)
>
> Generating Pods project
>
> Integrating client project
>
> Sending stats
>
> Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 
>   total pod installed.

Then based off of all the advice/suggestions of various SOF posts involving this same sort of error, I did the following:

- Made sure the Build Active Architectures Only are identical between my project/target + Pods
- Added $(inherited) to the top of other linker flags
- Added $(inherited) to Framework search paths
- Added $(inherited) to Library Search Paths
  (This shows build/Debug-iphoneos/TheAmazingAudioEngine"
- Added $(inherited) and COCOAPODS=1 to Preprocessor Macros
- Made sure Link Binary With Libraries has libPods-MyApp.a
- Deleted the Pods folder, Podfile.lock and my .xcworkspace file, and did "pod install && pod update"
- Cleaned the project

...

basically, no matter what I do, when I build, I always get:

```
Ld /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hjfppqmgxqrprucknvwtakynpqxs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.app/myapp normal arm64
    cd /Users/patrick/MyApp
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk -L/Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hjfppqmgxqrprucknvwtakynpqxs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hjfppqmgxqrprucknvwtakynpqxs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TheAmazingAudioEngine -L/Users/patrick/MyApp/build/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hjfppqmgxqrprucknvwtakynpqxs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hjfppqmgxqrprucknvwtakynpqxs/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/myapp.LinkFileList -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -dead_strip -fembed-bitcode-marker -ObjC -ObjC -lTheAmazingAudioEngine -framework Accelerate -framework AudioToolbox -ObjC -lz -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -lPods-MyApp -framework CoreMIDI -framework Security -framework CoreData -framework StoreKit /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hjfppqmgxqrprucknvwtakynpqxs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocosDenshion.a -framework Accelerate -framework CoreLocation /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hjfppqmgxqrprucknvwtakynpqxs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libkazmath.a -framework CoreMotion -framework CoreText -framework AudioToolbox -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenGLES -framework OpenAL -framework AVFoundation -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework GameKit /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hjfppqmgxqrprucknvwtakynpqxs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libcocos2d.a -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hjfppqmgxqrprucknvwtakynpqxs/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/myapp_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hjfppqmgxqrprucknvwtakynpqxs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.app/myapp

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/patrick/MyApp/build/Debug-iphoneos'
ld: library not found for -lTheAmazingAudioEngine
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to `Build Settings`

2) Select `Other Linker Flags`

3) Add -l"TheAmazingAudioEngine"

4) Rebuild

Try it